# Iterating through a python list of list and creating a new list

Tags: python, ruby, enumeration

Basically, I have a dictionary of the form:

```
'the trip':('The Trip','www.SearchHero.com',"See sponsored listings for 'The Trip.' Click here!",0.1,'The Trip','3809466'), 
'post office':('Post Office','www.SearchHero.com',"See sponsored listings for 'Post Office.' Click here!",0.1,'Post Office','5803938'), 
'balanced diets':('Last Minute Deals','www.SearchHero.com',"See sponsored listings for 'Last Minute Deals.' Click here!",0.1,'Last Minute Deals','1118375')
```

I want to output a list of the form:

`{'.1, 3809466', '.1, 5803938', '.1, '1118375'}`

I am new to Python, but in Ruby I know I'd use the map function. What is the equivalent in python? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic example:

```
['%f, %s' % (x,y) for _,_,_,x,_,y in d.values()]
```

you can adapt the format string to have more control over the output.
The underlying syntax construct is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

```
[', '.join((value[3], value[5])) for value in my_dict.iteritems()]
```

Comment: you are missing a parenthesis somewhere?